# Is it possible to rotate an IBDesignable UIButton using Swift?

Tags: swift

How to make an IBDesignable component that has an angle: CGFloat property that rotates the view

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyB: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable
    var angle: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            //What to put here?
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I tried

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work". The fact that you've declared this as IBDesignable isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: "doesn't work" meaning when I change the angle in the inspector in Interface Builder, the UIButton's frame doesn't rotate

Comment: This seems like a genuine bug as of Xcode 6 beta 4, so I submitted a test project as bug report 17764377 to Apple. Views will rotate correctly when the app is run, but CGAffineTransformMakeRotation has no effect in Live View regardless of various refreshes I tried to force.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@IBInspectable not updating Story Board](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545455/ibinspectable-not-updating-story-board)

Comment: look ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37300130/294884

Answer (score 4):

You should create `CustomButton` inherited from `UIButton`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var rotation: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            rotateButton(rotation: rotation)
        }
    }

    func rotateButton(rotation: Double)  {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi/2 + rotation))
    }
}
```

You will get following output,

[image]

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work in the latest XCode