# @IBInspectable not updating Story Board

Tags: uiview, interface-builder, swift2, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

My custom button below works fine on the iOS Simulator - when I set a rotation in Interface Builder it rotates the button when I run the app.

However, I can't see the rotation in the Story Board - it just shows the button without applying the transformation.

It doesn't matter if I do the transformation inside the `drawRect` method - same result.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


@IBDesignable class CustomButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var rotation: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(rotation))
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674111/ib-designable-ibinspectable-interface-builder-does-not-update?rq=1

Comment: @uraimo I saw this before posting my question, but my Xcode was already auto updating.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is safe to say "It is `@IBDesignable` **Bug** in `Xcode 7.1.1`"

Because:

1. Running project does show the `CGAffineTransform` with the given rotation.
2. If `borderWidth`, `borderColor` etc. are changed in this `didSet` block, it shows in the `Storyboard` correctly.
3. I could not find anything in the apple developer site that says transformation will not work for `@IBDesignable`

Comment: I think I must agree with you. I have filed a bug report with Apple, so maybe they will fix it.